# HTTP 400 Bad request - Only on JBoss Server

Tags: java, web-services, rest, http, jboss-eap-6

I have a Rest service class, which intends to update the inventory using PUT method via REST web service.
When I call the service class by Junit or main class (`Public static void main`)  then the inventory got update and i don't get any issue.

But the same service class throws exception when it's deployed to JBOSS-eap server and called by remote method, I see the following error in log,

```
HTTP 400 - Bad Error
sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://www.webstore.com
```

Please see below the piece of code,

```
       URL apiUrl = new URL("https://...");

        String authToBytes = username + ":" + password;
        byte authBytes[] = Base64.encodeBase64(authToBytes.getBytes());
        String authBytesString = new String(authBytes);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) apiUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");

        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/XML");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authBytesString);


            OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            output.write(body.getBytes()); //String body ="XML Data.."
            output.flush();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) { // Got exception on JBoss only
            throw new CustomException(conn.getResponseCode() + "", conn.getResponseMessage());
        }
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
```

Comment: As can be seen from your question everything works fine when application is deployed on different server (like Tomcat, for example). So application logic is correct. As you deal with XML it is very probable that the issue is caused by conflicts of libraries which are responsible for XML transformations (JBoss already contains its own implementation of such libraries). But for precise answer more logs are required.

Comment: @flaz14 I haven't tested on tomcat but just tried using Junit test and it got successful.
I will put more log details for you.